# JSON string with 2 formats

Tags: c#, json

```cs
String quoteIn = "{\"T\":\"q\",\"S\":\"AAPL\",\"bx\":\"Q\",\"bp\":145.67,\"bs\":14,\"ax\":\"K\",\"ap\":145.68,\"as\":6,\"c\":[\"R\"],\"z\":\"C\",\"t\":\"2021-08-10T18:49:47.469842Z\"}";
String quoteIn2 = "{\"T\":\"q\",\"S\":\"AAPL\",\"bx\":\"Q\",\"bp\":145.6,\"bs\":13,\"ax\":\"P\",\"ap\":145.61,\"as\":11,\"c\":[\"R\"],\"z\":\"C\",\"t\":\"2021-08-10T19:07:30.681679Z\"},{\"T\":\"q\",\"S\":\"AAPL\",\"bx\":\"Q\",\"bp\":145.6,\"bs\":13,\"ax\":\"P\",\"ap\":145.61,\"as\":10,\"c\":[\"R\"],\"z\":\"C\",\"t\":\"2021-08-10T19:07:30.681713152Z\"}";
```

make a simple presentation 
format 1: `{"T":"q",...}` 
format 2: `{{"T":"q",...}, {"T":"q",...}}`

Question is how to process both of them?\

If format 1, I use the following:

```cs
var quote = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Quote>>(quoteIn);
```

which works

but if format 2, I use the following:

```cs
var quote2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Quote>>(quoteIn2);
```

then it error out saying:

```
ex.Message  "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JasonTest.Quote]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'T', line 1, position 5." string
```

Please help!

Comment: Could you please [edit] the post to provide [MCVE], including the data portion - sample JSON  is super hard to read and looks like contains huge amount of content not directly related to the question you trying to ask? Also `quoteIn2` does not even look like valid JSON... - is that the problem you trying to solve?

Comment: This is not valid JSON: `quoteIn2` is not valid because it is missing array brackets `[]`. format 2 has braces `{}` instead of brackets `[]`. Either way it's not going to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used System.text.jason to fixed above issue.

Use Jsondocument JsonElement.ArrayEnumerator to loop through each one of them

and use JasonElement.GetRawText to get string and deserialize into a C# class instance.

Only downside is you have to upgrade project to .Net Core 5.0

Answer (score 3):

Format 2 is not a valid format and not an array:

```
{{"T":"q",...}, {"T":"q",...}}
```

should be:

```
[{"T":"q",...}, {"T":"q",...}]
```